# How to see offscreen undo changes?

Tags: formatting, scrolling, undo-redo, multiple-lines

Imagine a text file with some words on the first line, one-thousand blank lines, and some text on the last line.

```
this is a first line of text.
<1000 blank lines>
Last line of text.
```

From the first line make a change and go to the last line by typing exactly: `A This change will be invisible when undone from offscreen.<ESC>G`.

The text is now:

```
this is a first line of text. This change will be invisible when undone from offscreen.
<1000 blank lines>
Last line of text.
```

and the cursor is on the last line and you can't see the first line.

We can press `u` to undo the change, but because we started offscreen from where the change actually occurred,  we don't see what was undone; we just see the text as it was before the change and we have to remember what the change was that was just undone. This was a simple example but what the offscreen change was can be difficult when acutally working.

So my question is, does anyone know a way to 'preview' offscreen undos before they come into effect so that you can actually see specifically what is being undone? Or some other similar solution.

Comment: normally, pressing `u` moves the cursor (and hence the view) back to the changed line

Comment: That's right but you don't see what was changed. The undo has already appened when view is at the undo location.

Comment: Aside from toggling `<C-r>` and `u`, there’s the undotree and some plugins (at least one of which includes a small diff preview)

Comment: built-in, there's always `'.`, `g;` etc.

Comment: Yeah, as noted above I just do an extra `u` and `<c-r>`. For those times when multiple steps are impacted I fire up undotree which opens up two windows: the undo history and a diff that shows what changed between the currently selected history entry and the previous entry.